# New ag-grid CSS import path throws error during build process in my react app

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm doing some changes to my React project (React version: 16.13.1, created with CRA) in order to upgrade from v27 to v28 of Ag-Grid. [One of the changes requested is the new way to import the css files](https://ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/themes/#javascript-bundlers). It used to be

`import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css'`

and now it has to be like this:

`import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css'`

This is generates an error during the build process:

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css
ParserError: Syntax Error at line: 1, column 83


error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

This makes me think it is a webpack problem, maybe a loader?. If it is the case, is there a way to handle this error without ejecting the webpack config?

Other clues I explored:

- is it because I try to import CSS from a module?
- is it a problem with the react version (16.13.1)?

Any ideas and solutions will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can find more details on this issue on the following [Github Issue](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/5580) which is related to a known [issue with CRA 3.x](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/discussions/10095)

The main thing to note is that we will be applying a fix in v28.2 which is due out next week.

> AG-7222 Add Post Processing of CSS for CRA 3.x/4.x Compatibility which should help address this issue will be released as part of our next release 28.2 and should resolve these issues without the need for a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

CSS file *ag-grid.css* has two syntax errors. Calc() function is missing in two places.

```
line-height: min(var(--ag-line-height, calc(var(--ag-row-height) - 2px)), var(--ag-row-height) - 2px);
```

This should be:

```
line-height: min(var(--ag-line-height, calc(var(--ag-row-height) - 2px)), calc(var(--ag-row-height) - 2px));
```

And..

```
height: min(var(--ag-line-height, calc(var(--ag-row-height) - 2px)), var(--ag-row-height) - 2px);
```

should be:

```
height: min(var(--ag-line-height, calc(var(--ag-row-height) - 2px)), calc(var(--ag-row-height) - 2px));
```

Correcting these issues resolved above build error in my case.